# jQuery duplicate form with increment ID doesn't work the duplicated forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a unique id and a button to do a calculation. I have another button to duplicate the form as much as you want before doing the calculation. I was able to duplicate the form and it's sub fields with an unique ID. But with the help of stackoverflow I've written the code to calculate only the first form. How I can modify my code to calculate the whole duplicated forms.

```js
var myJson = {
    "platforms": [
        {
            "name": "Sitecore",
            "id": "Sitecore",
            "tasktype": [
                {
                    "name": "Promobox",
                    "id": "Promobox",
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "name": "Box 0",
                            "id": "box0",
                            "time": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Box 1",
                            "id": "box1",
                            "time": "30"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Video",
                    "id": "Video",
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "name": "Box 2",
                            "id": "box2",
                            "time": "25"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Box 3",
                            "id": "box3",
                            "time": "30"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Siab",
            "id": "Siab",
            "tasktype": [
                {
                    "name": "Newswire",
                    "id": "Newswire",
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "name": "Box 4",
                            "id": "box5",
                            "time": "50"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Box 5",
                            "id": "box5",
                            "time": "40"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Task Type New",
                    "id": "Task Type New",
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "name": "Box 6",
                            "id": "box6",
                            "time": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Box 7",
                            "id": "box7",
                            "time": "100"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};



$.each(myJson.platforms, function (index, value) {
    var platform_id;
    var tasktype_id;
    var component_id;

    $("#platform").append('<option rel="' + index + '" value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');

    $("#platform").change(function () {
        $("#tasktype, #component").find("option:gt(0)").remove();
        $("#tasktype").find("option:first").text("Loading...");

        platform_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');

        $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype, function (index1, value1) {
            $("#tasktype").find("option:first").text("Select Task Type");
            $("#tasktype").append('<option rel="' + index1 + '" value="' + value1.id + '">' + value1.name + '</option>');
        });

    });


    $("#tasktype").change(function () {
        $("#component").find("option:gt(0)").remove();
        $("#component").find("option:first").text("Loading...");

        tasktype_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');

        $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype[tasktype_id].components, function (index2, value2) {
            $("#component").find("option:first").text("Select Component");
            $("#component").append('<option rel="' + index2 + '" value="' + value2.time + '">' + value2.name + '</option>');
        });


    });
    
    
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calculate').click(function () {
        let tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo("#data tbody");
          $('#calc input, #calc select').each( function (index) {
              var input = $(this);
              $(tr).append('<td class=row-'+ $(input).attr("id") + '>' + $(input).val() + '</td>');
            });
            
            const componentFactor = $(tr).children(".row-component").text();
            const units = $(tr).children(".row-units").text();
            const total = componentFactor*units;

            $(tr).append('<td>' + total + '</td>');
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
    var calc_index=0;
    $("#addNew").click(function(){
        calc_index++;
        $("#calc").after($("#calc").clone().attr("id","calc" + calc_index));
        $("#calc" + calc_index).css("display","inline");
        $("#calc" + calc_index + " :input").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") + calc_index);
            $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id") + calc_index);
            });

    });
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calculate').click(function () {
        let tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo("#data tbody");
          $('#calc1 input, #calc1 select').each( function (index) {
              var input = $(this);
              $(tr).append('<td class=row-'+ $(input).attr("id") + '>' + $(input).val() + '</td>');
            });
            
            const componentFactor = $(tr).children(".row-component").text();
            const units = $(tr).children(".row-units").text();
            const total = componentFactor*units;

            $(tr).append('<td>' + total + '</td>');
        });
    });


    $("#clear").click(function(){
        location.reload();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Production Units Calculator</h2>
    
    <div class="formset">
    <form id="calc">
    <label>Platform:</label>
    <select id="platform" name="platform">
      <option value="0">Select Platform</option>
    </select>
    <label>Task Type:</label>
    <select id="tasktype" name="tasktype">
      <option value="0">Select Task Type</option>
    </select>
    <label>Component:</label>
    <select id="component" name="component">
      <option value="0">Select Component</option>
    </select>
    <label>Units:</label>
    <input name="units" id="units" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Input Units"/>
    <br />
    </form>
    </div>

<button id="calculate" >Calculate</button>
<button id="addNew" >Add New</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>


<table style="width:50%" id="data">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Platform</th>
    <th>Task Type</th>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Units</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody></tbody>

</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use clone and class names. Then you can use relative addressing like `$(".tasktype").change(function () { $(this).closest("tr").find(".component")` ...

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Comment: jQuery is excellent in navigating between siblings and children of things. When you add a row, give all the input fields a class. Then the calculate button can use $(this).closest("tr") to find the parent and .find(".classOfWhatever") to navigate to the relevant fields.

Answer (score 0):

used `selectors` on `form`. May it help

```js
var myJson = {
  "platforms": [{
    "name": "Sitecore",
    "id": "Sitecore",
    "tasktype": [{
      "name": "Promobox",
      "id": "Promobox",
      "components": [{
        "name": "Box 0",
        "id": "box0",
        "time": "20"
      }, {
        "name": "Box 1",
        "id": "box1",
        "time": "30"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Video",
      "id": "Video",
      "components": [{
        "name": "Box 2",
        "id": "box2",
        "time": "25"
      }, {
        "name": "Box 3",
        "id": "box3",
        "time": "30"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Siab",
    "id": "Siab",
    "tasktype": [{
      "name": "Newswire",
      "id": "Newswire",
      "components": [{
        "name": "Box 4",
        "id": "box5",
        "time": "50"
      }, {
        "name": "Box 5",
        "id": "box5",
        "time": "40"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Task Type New",
      "id": "Task Type New",
      "components": [{
        "name": "Box 6",
        "id": "box6",
        "time": "20"
      }, {
        "name": "Box 7",
        "id": "box7",
        "time": "100"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

$(function() {
  var platform_id;
  var tasktype_id;
  var component_id;
  $.each(myJson.platforms, function(index, value) {


    $("#platform").append('<option rel="' + index + '" value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');

    $("#platform").change(function() {
      $("#tasktype, #component").find("option:gt(0)").remove();
      $("#tasktype").find("option:first").text("Loading...");

      platform_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');

      $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype, function(index1, value1) {
        $("#tasktype").find("option:first").text("Select Task Type");
        $("#tasktype").append('<option rel="' + index1 + '" value="' + value1.id + '">' + value1.name + '</option>');
      });

    });

  });
  $("#tasktype").change(function() {
    $("#component").find("option:gt(0)").remove();
    $("#component").find("option:first").text("Loading...");

    tasktype_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('rel');

    $.each(myJson.platforms[platform_id].tasktype[tasktype_id].components, function(index2, value2) {
      $("#component").find("option:first").text("Select Component");
      $("#component").append('<option rel="' + index2 + '" value="' + value2.time + '">' + value2.name + '</option>');
    });


  });


});



$(function() {
  var calc_index = 0;
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    calc_index++;
    if (calc_index != 1)
      $("#calc" + (calc_index - 1)).after($("#calc").clone().attr("id", "calc" + calc_index));
    else
      $("#calc").after($("#calc").clone().attr("id", "calc" + calc_index));

    $("#calc" + calc_index).css("display", "inline");
    $("#calc" + calc_index + " :input").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + calc_index);
      $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + calc_index);
    });

  });

  $('#calculate').click(function() {

    $("form[id^='calc']").each(function(index) {
      let tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo("#data tbody");
      $(this).find('input,select').each(function() {
        $(tr).append('<td class=row-' + $(this).attr("id") + '>' + $(this).val() + '</td>');
      });

      $(tr).append('<td class="row-total">' + 0 + '</td>');
    });
    $("#data tbody").find('tr').each(function() {
      var $tr = $(this);
      let componentFactor = $tr.children("td[class^='row-component']").text();
      let units = $tr.children("td[class^='row-units']").text();
      let total = $tr.children("td[class^='row-total']").text();
      if ((componentFactor != "" || units != "") && total == 0) {
        $tr.children("td[class^='row-total']").text(componentFactor * units);
      }
    });


  });
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    $("#data tbody").empty();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Production Units Calculator</h2>

<div class="formset">
  <form id="calc">
    <label>Platform:</label>
    <select id="platform" name="platform">
      <option value="0">Select Platform</option>
    </select>
    <label>Task Type:</label>
    <select id="tasktype" name="tasktype">
      <option value="0">Select Task Type</option>
    </select>
    <label>Component:</label>
    <select id="component" name="component">
      <option value="0">Select Component</option>
    </select>
    <label>Units:</label>
    <input name="units" id="units" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Input Units" />
    <br />
  </form>
</div>

<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<button id="addNew">Add New</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>


<table style="width:50%" id="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Platform</th>
      <th>Task Type</th>
      <th>Component</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```